# как перейти на другой view controller без использования Segue

Tags: xcode, swift

В проекте использую библиотеку `SideMenuSwiftDemo` для анимации меню.
Как используя эти функции перейти на другой `View` контролер?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
class kConstant {
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

func SetIntialMainViewController(aStoryBoardID: String)->(KSideMenuVC){
    let sideMenuObj = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftMenu")
    let mainVcObj = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(aStoryBoardID)
    let navigationController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVcObj)
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
    sideMenuVC.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    sideMenuVC.setMainViewController(navigationController)()
    sideMenuVC.setMenuViewController(sideMenuObj)()
    return sideMenuVC
}
func SetMainViewController(aStoryBoardID: String)->(KSideMenuVC){
    let mainVcObj = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(aStoryBoardID)
    let navigationController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVcObj)
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
    sideMenuVC.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    sideMenuVC.setMainViewController(navigationController)()
    return sideMenuVC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, глянуть в [демо-проект](https://github.com/kiran5232/SideMenuSwiftDemo/blob/master/SideMenuSwiftDemo/SideMenuVC.swift):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        kConstantObj.SetIntialMainViewController("firstVC") // Переход
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        kConstantObj.SetIntialMainViewController("secondVC") // Переход
    }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        kConstantObj.SetIntialMainViewController("thirdVC") // Переход
    }
}
```

В скобках изменить на свои `Storyboard ID`